# Spring plugin does not deploy on virgo

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-virgo

I have a simple plugin. I just need to deploy it in virgo server but unfortunately receive this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already try the hints given in the [Virgo FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Virgo/FAQ#How_can_I_diagnose_class_loading_problems.3F)? (How can I diagnose class loading problems?):

- [Troubleshooting class loading issues with Virgo](http://hsiliev.blogspot.de/2010/12/troubleshooting-class-loading-issues-in.html)
- [Virgo Shell Commands](http://eclipse.org/virgo/documentation/virgo-documentation-3.6.3.RELEASE/docs/virgo-user-guide/html/ch08s02.html) (clhas, clload, ...)